# Nested Controller's create Action respond_to Fails To Render :new If Save Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, action, actioncontroller

I have a nested `Photo` controller with the following action:

```
  def create
    @photo = @gallery.photos.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Created new photo"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't create photo"
    end
   respond_with [@gallery, @photo]
  end
```

If the photo params are valid, it redirects to `gallery_photo_path` correctly, however if the params are invalid and @photo doesn't save successfully, rather than rendering the `:new` template as I would expect, it redirects to `/galleries/1/photos` which doesn't exist.

If I don't use `respond_with` and hardcode the render, everything works fine:

```
  def create
    @photo = @gallery.photos.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Created new photo"
      redirect_to gallery_photo_path @gallery, @photo
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't create photo"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Why does `respond_to` fail to render the new template when the save fils as outlined in [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with)?

**Notes**

I am using `respond_to :html` in the controller and all other actions behave as expected.

Comment: You did pair it with `respond_to` in your controller, right?

Comment: Yes i did. Other actions all use it without issues.

Comment: Hmm, on small difference is that in the docs it says `respond_with(@gallery, @photo)`, so they don't use an explicit array. Shouldn't make a difference, but one never knows...

Comment: @Vapire Great spot. That was it. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Ha, I guess `Array#errors` doesn't exist :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs state to use the `respond_with` with the objects as parameters, not with an explicit array, so

```
respond_with [@gallery, @photo]
```

should be

```
respond_with(@gallery, @photo)
```